# Will recursively-called variable be free or bound?

Tags: scope, scheme, racket, free-variable, bound-variable

I am trying to have a better understanding about free and bound variables. Here is an example code:

```
(define (what-kind-of-var? guess x)
    (< (abs (- (square guess) x))
        0.001))
```

I see that bound variables here would be `guess` and `x`, and free variables `<`, `abs`, `-`, and `square`. What if I called `what-kind-of-var?` recursively? Would it be a bound variable because it is binding itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would, under dynamic binding, but Scheme has lexical scoping.

But actually it is neither. "Free" or "bound" comes from lambda calculus. `what-kind-of-var?` is a *top-level variable*, naming that lambda expression,

```
(define what-kind-of-var? 
  (lambda (guess x)                        ;; this
     (< (abs (- (square guess) x))
         0.001)))
```

but in lambda calculus expressions cannot be named. The only way to call it recursively in lambda calculus is to use **Y** combinator:

```
((Y (lambda (what-kind-of-var?)                ;; outer
      (lambda (guess x)                            ;; inner
         (if (< (abs (- (square guess) x))
                0.001)
           guess
           (what-kind-of-var? (+ 1 guess) x)))))
  4 25)
```

and now of course `what-kind-of-var?` *is* bound inside that new lambda expression under `Y`. It's free in the nested, inner lambda, but bound in the outer one.

Comment: r7rs got dynamic binding too https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-39/srfi-39.html

Comment: I think the ideas of free and bound appeared also in the works of Frege (about 1880?).  Lambda calculus defined them precisely but they for sure appeared before.

Comment: A. not the language itself, but as an extension. B. we're in Scheme, so LC is what's relevant. of course LC itself is a development of the "open formula" concept (i.e. a logical formula with free variables)

Comment: dynamic binding is standardized now, following the request for Implementation I pasted.  New versions of scheme will contain it in their kernel by default.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/cowan/r7rs-wg1-infra/src/default/R7RSHomePage.md

Comment: mit-scheme also passed to R7RS I think , not sure that they updated it completely

Comment: the default scoping is still lexical though, correct?

Comment: default is lexical, dynamic is inside the `parameterize` form.  By default this form will be present in the next future of scheme.  So far it was only optional , some of implementors wanted to have optionally that request of implementation.

Comment: but the default scope for a given Scheme variable will still be lexical. to get dynamic one would have to use some special form.

Comment: yes, the default way of binding is static, as so far.  Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

- `guess` and `x` are parameters. They're eventually bound (to respective arguments) when the function is applied.
- `<`, `abs`, `-`, are actually bound to procedures in the initial environment. So they're not free variables.
- `square` would be the free variable, subject to the fact that `what-kind-of-var?` is not defined in its scope. (note that `sqr` is bound in the initial environment).
- `what-kind-of-var?` is also not unbound, even if it calls itself recursively (assuming recursion is implemented properly in the language). `(define (f param) body)` can be seen as `(define f (lambda (param) body)`

Comment: They're free in this expression, for sure. They may be bound in the global environment, but in this expression they are free.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that the function would be typed out in an editor. But if we consider _only_ this expression then, yes, they're free.